# Wp_new_user_notification doesn't work

Tags: email

I have tried unsuccessfully to replace the email template for user & password.

I will explain what I have done based on the documentation and what I have seen here in this forum:

I have created my own plugin with the following code:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
  
        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
  
        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "rn";
  
        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
  
        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;
  
        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= __('Adios!');
  
        wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
  
    }
}
```

I have also added the following filter using the code snippets plugin:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
   // filter stuff in $wp_new_user_notification_email here
   return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Finally I inserted the same plugin code in a php file called user-email.php in the following path:

**/wp-content/mu-plugin/user-email.php**

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
  
        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
  
        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "rn";
  
        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
  
        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;
  
        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "rn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "rnrn";
        $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "rnrn";
        $message .= __('Adios!');
  
        wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
  
    }
}
```

None of the options mentioned above has worked and the "Your username and password info" default email is the one that keeps coming. I'm already a bit worried because apparently this is the only possible solution for this case.

Does anyone have any idea that it may be failing?